# ¿Cómo averiguo el tamaño de la pantalla en PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Antes de nada, deciros que soy un principiante en esto de la programación web. Estoy intentando que según sea la anchura de la pantalla, elegir el total de páginas de videos que veremos en pantalla al mismo tiempo. Como estoy trabajando con bootstrap, averiguo cuando la pantalla es xm, sm, md o lg (xl actúa como lg) para extraer de una base de datos mySQL las filas que ocupen un pantallazo y posteriormente visualizar todos los videos a través de una paginación.

Para saber en qué pantalla estamos lo hago con este script:

```
if (!isset($pantalla)) {
     $pantalla =
         '<script> 
 if (screen.width < 576) 
    document.write ("xm") 
 else if (screen.width < 768) 
       document.write ("sm") 
 else if (screen.width < 992) 
       document.write ("md")      
    else 
       document.write ("lg") 
 </script>';
 }
```

Si hacemos un echo $pantalla; aparece, por ejemplo, 'lg'. Sigo, para establecer el número de videos que vamos a ver por página lo hago con simples if:

```
if ($pantalla == 'xm') {
    $videos_por_pagina = 1;
} else if ($pantalla == 'sm') {
    $videos_por_pagina = 4;
} else if ($pantalla == 'md') {
    $videos_por_pagina = 6;
} else if ($pantalla == 'lg') {
    $videos_por_pagina = 8;
} else {
    $videos_por_pagina = '* ERROR *';
}
```

Si hacemos un echo $videos_por_pagina; siempre aparece '* ERROR *'.

Lo he dado mil vueltas y ya estoy loco. Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería eternamente. Gracias.

Comment: Para poder elegir cuantos videos o cosas mostrar rn la pantalla existe la propiedad *flex* y *grid* de css lo que hará es ajustar el contenido dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla y contenedor en el que se encuentren, no necesitas hacer todo lo que haces con js y php a menos que lo quieras hacer así

Comment: Podrías usar ajax para eso. Capturas con javascript y envías a php los valores de la pantalla. Pero lo ideal es que hagas eso directacmente con los menús responsive.

Comment: Gracias. Lo necesito para establecer un LIMIT en la consulta sql de la base de datos.  En pantalla ya lo tengo establecido con las clases de bootstrap

Comment: En PHP, lo más que puedes obtener es el tipo de dispositivo, tal vez usando alguna clase o librería, como [esta](http://mobiledetect.net/) y tomar la posible resolución máxima como referencia. Definitivamente con solo PHP no vas a obtener el tamaño de pantalla.